# GWT - Styling TreeItems

Tags: css, gwt

in my application I have a tree structure made out of treeitems.

What I wanted to do was change the background of certain tree items if their userObject satisfies certain conditions.  The problem I have is when a root tree item is getting its background changed (only tested it on criteria being satisfied at tree items at the root level), all child treeitems of that tree item also have their background changed despite me going in and removing that style sheet on the children.

Long story short: I want it to only change the background on the tree item itself, and not its children.

code:

```
        if(item.getUserObject() != null && ((Device)item.getUserObject()).getDeviceType() == type)
        {
            item.setStyleName("labelHighlight");
        }
        else
        {
            item.removeStyleName("labelHighlight");
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < item.getChildCount(); i++)
        {
            highlightNodes(type, item.getChild(i));
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a widget instead of directly styling treeItem. Like this, you can change background of your widget and not the background of all your tree item